# Laravel 5.2 Multi Auth Not getting logged in user data

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I am developing a web application with laravel 5.2 multi auth.

here is my code.

Auth.php

```
  'guards' => [
    'a' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'b' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'customers',
    ],
],



   'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'customers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Customer::class,
    ],
],
```

IndexController.php

```
 public function doLogin(){
    $credentails = [
        'name'      =>Input::get('name'),
        'password'  =>Input::get('password')
    ];

    if(Auth::guard('a')->attempt($credentails)){
        return Redirect::to(route('sessionviewa'));
    }else{
        return "Login Error";
    }
}


public function logout(){
    Auth::guard('a')->logout();
    return "succeess";
}

public function SessionViewA(){
    dd(Auth::guard('a')->user());
}

public function SessionViewB(){
    dd(Auth::guard('b')->user());
}
```

Routes.

```
 Route::post('dologin',['as'=>'dologin','uses'=>'IndexController@doLogin']); 

Route::get('sessiona',['as'=>'sessionviewa','uses'=>'IndexController@SessionViewA']); 
Route::get('sessionb',['as'=>'sessionviewb','uses'=>'IndexController@SessionViewB']);
```

I can login successfully, but not getting logged in user data. ?

Now its returning as null in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using Laravel 5.2, I have this problem also before.

I solve this by putting my route into the web middleware group in route.php. This way, I can access the Auth and get the user I want.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // Your route here
});
```

Try it and let me know its working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nizam, so obvious yet I just wasted a couple of hours on it :).

I'd like to point out that my problem was that though I did have the middleware specified in the route group where the login happens, I was trying to access the authenticated user from a different group that didn't - banging my head why it doesn't work. The moral of the story is, of course, have the middleware on each route where you need access to the guard.